# Angular: what is the difference between declaring a service in a component and the bootstrap process

Tags: angular

What is the different between this:

```
bootstrap(AppComponent, [HeroService]);
```

And this:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'test',
  providers: [HeroService]
})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you add it only to `bootstrap()` you get a singleton, if you add it to the component you get a new instance for each component instance. If you add it to both then it depends on where you inject it. Angular2 has a hierarchical DI. It searches upwards for a provider, the first it founds is returned.

See also
http://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2015/05/18/dependency-injection-in-angular-2.html

Answer (score 1):

When you pass `HeroService` as a dependency to the `bootstrap` method then the `HeroService` behaves as a singleton - with one single instance of the class available throughout your application.

Passing it in the `providers` array will create a new instance of the service.

Take a look at [this article](http://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2015/09/17/resolve-service-dependencies-in-angular-2.html) for a detailed explanation of dependency injection in Angular 2.

Answer (score 1):

When you declare provider in bootstrap it will be available to all components in your application. If you declare it inside the component it will be available only inside that component.

Make sure you don't include it in both places or you will create new instance inside the component and overwrite the instance from bootstrap.